# How to get maxSpeculativeExecutions from ConstantSpeculativeExecutionPolicy?

Tags: scala, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have the following code snippet:

```
case x: ConstantSpeculativeExecutionPolicy =>
  x.getMaxSpeculativeExecutions shouldEqual 3
  x.getConstantDelayMillis shouldEqual 500
```

While compiling it I am facing the following error:

```
value getMaxSpeculativeExecutions is not a member of com.datastax.driver.core.policies.ConstantSpeculativeExecutionPolicy
```

I am using:

```
"com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "3.2.0"
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by explicitly adding the following dependencies to the `build.sbt` file:

```
"com.datastax.dse" % "dse-java-driver-core" % "1.8.2"
"com.datastax.dse" % "dse-java-driver-mapping" % "1.8.2"
```